# Is Ctrl+Shift+Arrow gone from WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

I adore the feature in WebStorm that moves the current block (not line, not selection) up and down by block (not by line). On Windows it is/was Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down. For example you could change the order of sequential functions with a single command without selection.

Before:

```
function first() {
   ...
}

function second() {  // WITH CURSOR HERE, HIT CTRL+SHIFT+UP
   ...
}

function third() {  
   ...
}
```

After:

```
function second() {   // TA-DA!!
   ...
}

function first() {
   ...
}

function third() {  
   ...
}
```

It doesn't appear to work anymore after the most recent WS update to 2020.3.

(Neither does Ctrl+. as basically equivalent to alt+enter)

If I knew what the command was called I could reassign it but I never got to it from anywhere besides the key command which I discovered accidentally.

Anyone know?

Comment: 1) What Keymap do you use? `Settings | Keymap` -- maybe you are using different keymap now (got reset somehow during upgrade), so try another one. 2) What shortcuts that action has? You can also check it in `Main Menu | Code | Move Statement Up/Down`. 3) Does it work if you use that action via menu?

Comment: Good point, I'm using the VS Code map. However, your actual answer of "which command is this?" is what I need. Feel free to post as an answer so I can approve it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that in your keymap it has completely different shortcuts.

The actual action can be invoked using mouse from main menu: `Code | Move Statement Up` (and the opposite `Code | Move Statement Down`).

You can check what shortcut is has in your keymap and change it as needed at `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` (use local search field to narrow down the list).

[image]

[image]